# Retrieve <Version> tag written in csproj file from dll

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-assembly, csproj

I have a c# project and I also written into csproj file the tag 1.0.1; I compiled the project and obtained a dll corresponding to my project, but I don't know how to retrieve the value of the Version attribute from the DLL?